# Wrong localization with geopy

Tags: python, google-maps, geopy

I am using geopy to geolocate some French Paris streets.
I have seen a problem on this localisation: 25 rue Constantine, Paris.

The code below:

```
location2 = geolocator.geocode("25 rue Constantine, Paris",timeout=20)
arrival=(location2.latitude, location2.longitude)
print arrival
```

Gives those latitude and longitude for this street:

(45.1586776, 5.7459736)

which is close to French Grenoble city (about 450 km away from Paris !).

Do you know what could be the problem ?

By advance thank you.

Cheers,
Olivier

Answer (score 0):

It find "*2-4 Rue de Paris, 38320 Eybens*" according to Google maps.

It seems you've made a spelling mistake.
Are you perhaps looking for "*25 rue **de** Constantine, Paris*"?

Comment: Thanks a lot . That is true , the good address is "rue DE Constantine" :)